# Tricky sql distinct with Sql Geometry field

Tags: sql, sql-server, geometry, distinct

I have an sql statement that is not compatible with the `Sql Geometry` type so i am trying to revamp it to make it work.

The basic gist of it is something like this:

```
Select distinct A,B,C,D,SHAPE FROM TABLE1 UNION SELECT A,B,C,D,SHAPE FROM TABLE2
```

So the results of a complex distinct statement on two different (but similar) tables is unioned.

The problem is that the `SQL Geometry` type (the SHAPE field) cannot be included in a distinct statement because it is not a comparable type.

I'm okay with removing the `SHAPE` field from both of the subqueries that take part in the union. But i want to get it back after those subqueries are parsed.
I can get the `SHAPE` field if i know the value of column A.

**So my question is**: how can i remove a field from the distinct statements in the two subqueries but then get that field back (along with the rest of the fields) in the result set by joining it in on another column (A)?

Comment: Is it possible to add an ID field? You can use the ID value to easily track back the relevant field

Comment: I don't really know how to create tables or anything here. I think the union part is probably irrelevant if that breaks the problem down further. So consider a single table with 5 fields and some records. I want the records with distinct values in the first 3 fields. but i also want in the results the fifth field which cannot be included in a distinct statement

Comment: Yes. I have an ID field. That would represent column A in my question. I can use that ID field to get the SHAPE field in. How would i write that sql though?

Comment: I am a bit lost here. Do you want to insert the unique rows from both tables into a third table?

Comment: i want those unique rows to create a view

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? and what values you want distinct in output?

Comment: Table1---- Blah, boo, bar, fizz, SHAPE     Table 2 --- Blah, bling, bang, wow, SHAPE

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlspatial/thread/5310fb67-ac02-49f4-8bd2-87d1385444c9

Comment: both tables has same "uniqueID"? Hummm.. then thats not possible through uniqueID.. This will make it a bit complex.. give me few minutes

Comment: perhaps i worded my original question poorly. let me clarify slightly. These two select distincts are actually pulling from the same table. they just do it slightly differently and compute a few fields differently in each. in an attempt to simplify the question i glossed over too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast to VARBINARY(MAX), and then cast back.

```
create table tbl1 ( ID int, a int, b char(3), d geometry );
create table tbl2 ( ID int, a int, b char(3), d geometry, other float );
insert tbl1 (ID, a, b, d) values
    (1, 2, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0)),
    (2, 3, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0)),
    (3, 4, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0)),
    (4, 2, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 250 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0)),
    (5, 2, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 350 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0))
insert tbl2 (ID, a, b, d) values
    (6, 2, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 150 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0)), -- same as tbl1.ID=1
    (7, 2, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 950 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0)),
    (8, 2, 3, geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((0 0, 350 0, 150 150, 0 150, 0 0))', 0)); -- same as tbl1.ID=5

SELECT A, B, cast(c as geometry) c
FROM
(
    Select A,B,cast(D as varbinary(max)) c FROM tbl1
    UNION
    SELECT A,B,cast(D as varbinary(max)) FROM tbl2
) X;
```

Comment: Ok. that is along the lines of what i need. However, there is a caveat: each of the select subqueries does some massaging of the data to create a new field. Both of the subqueries do this and name the field the same, yet they do it in different ways. What i want to do is avoid your first SELECT A,B part and actually use the resulting records from the subqueries

Comment: As an answer to your clarification, no, it is not possible - you can't have your cake and eat it too. VARBINARY(MAX) is UNION-able (distinct) but you have to subquery it to transform it back to geometry.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW GeometryView1 AS
  SELECT A,B,C,D,SHAPE AS tabId FROM TABLE1 
  UNION SELECT A,B,C,D,SHAPE FROM TABLE2;

CREATE VIEW GeometryView2 AS
  SELECT DISTINCT A,B,C,D FROM (
  SELECT A,B,C,D AS tabId FROM TABLE1 
  UNION SELECT A,B,C,D FROM TABLE2) x;

SELECT DISTINCT v2.A,v2.B,v2.C,v2.D,v1.SHAPE FROM GeometryView2 v2 , GeometryView1 v1
WHERE v2.A=v1.A AND v2.B=v1.B AND v2.C=v1.C AND v2.D=v1.D
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
with cte as (
Select distinct A,B,C,D FROM TABLE1
)
select c.A,c.B,c.C,c.D,t.SHAPE 
FROM cte as c
inner join TABLE1 as t
   on c.A = t.A
UNION 
SELECT A,B,C,D,SHAPE FROM TABLE2
```