# Distinct geometry that don't exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using Sql Server 2012,

I am trying to do something like

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COMMUNITY FROM [TTDS].[dbo].[EXPORT_OUTPUT] WHERE COMMUNITY <> '') T1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT City FROM [TTDS].[dbo].[CITY]) T2 ON (T1.COMMUNITY = T2.City)
WHERE T2.City IS NULL
```

Where `EXPORT_OUTPUT` has a field `COMMUNITY` that has a bunch of duplicated values that may or may not be in `CITY`

For example `COMMUNITY` may have `a,a,a,a,b,b,c,d,e` and the `CITY`.`City` has `b,d,e` then it would output just `a,c`

---

This works all fine and well. This is the use-case but now instead of doing that with varchar fields, I want to do it with geometry. My attempt at it works but is very very slow.

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM (

    SELECT cast(UNIQUE_GEOM as geometry) [geometry_field]
    FROM
    (
        Select cast(Shape as varbinary(max)) as UNIQUE_GEOM FROM [TTDS].[dbo].[EXPORT_OUTPUT]
        UNION
        SELECT cast(Shape as varbinary(max)) FROM [TTDS].[dbo].[EXPORT_OUTPUT]
    ) GET_UNIQUE_GEOM

) T1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT [geometry] FROM [TTDS].[dbo].[LINKDIR_GEOMETRY]) T2 ON (T1.[geometry_field].STEquals(T2.[geometry]) = 1)
WHERE T2.[geometry] IS NULL
```

The `T1` is the table which has `DISTINCT` geometry from `EXPORT_OUTPUT`.

What is a more performant way to do this?

Comment: why you cast Shape to `varbinary` and then again to `geometry`? And why the both `union` parts  looks like is the same `select`?

Comment: You cant directly compare geometry. I saw another SO: ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752176/tricky-sql-distinct-with-sql-geometry-field ) that recommended casting to binary and doing this UNION with itself to find the distinct geometry in a table

Comment: But the select union. Both select do the same? in that case should be `SELECT distinct` without union.

Comment: Yes, this is to get the unique/distinct values. You cannot use `distinct` with geometry. If that was the case the answer would be trivial and almost identical to the varchar example.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is trying to join table by `geometry` using a function `STEquals` because that comparation take time specially without index.

For design database maybe have more sense

Have a table `geometry_objects` with fields `geometry_id` + `geom`

In that case you only put `geometry_id` both `comunity` and `city`

Comment: Both geometry fields have a spatial index on them. I have a table `geometry_objects` its what my `LINKDIR_GEOMETRY` that I am trying to  see from. I am trying to denormalize the output into the LINKDIR_GEOMETRY table.

Comment: Again you ask for performace, And split the table as my suggestion will improve the search by great porcentage. Because you will be comparing integers instead of geoms. Also `comunity` and `city` table will be smaller in size because `int` take less bytes than `geometry`. Also if you update a `geometry` only have to update one row in `geometry` table  instead all `comunity`and `city` rows with that geom

Comment: Community and city aren't even involved with the problem. I am denormalizing `[EXPORT_OUTPUT]` by selecting the values that are not in `LINKDIR_GEOMETRY` and inserting them (I don't insert in my example but that is the end result).

Comment: I believe you are suggesting to store the intermediate step of finding distinct geometries into an indexed table and then execute the join on that. In that case it still wouldnt be joining on int

Comment: Sorry I just read you 'for example' comment, if your query isn't related to that then rewrite the example. Is hard to guess what is doing your query if the things doesnt match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88421/discussion-between-juan-carlos-oropeza-and-parox).

Comment: When you say  `I am denormalizing` that should tell you the db model is wrong and you should normalize the db instead. And that is my suggestion for perforamance.

Comment: Sorry I meant normalizing.